# (Postgres) Query in a tree table in ascending and descending mode

Tags: postgresql, tree

I'm having some issues with two queries to search in a "tree" table.

So, my table is represented by the following code, and it has one only direction. However, I need to get data in both directions, ascending and descending mode.

```
create table graph_examle (input int null, output int );
insert into graph_examle (input, output) values
(null, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3 ),
(3, 4 ),
(null, 7 ),
(7,8),
(8, 4 ),
(null, 10 ),
(10, 11 ),
(11, 4),
(3, 15),
(25, 15),
(26, 15),
(15, 4 );
```

The ascending query has some issues. If I search by id 1, I'm expecting to see the relations:
1, 1->2, 1->2->3, 1->2->3->4, but the results are:

[image]

```
WITH recursive cte (initial_id, level, path, loop, input, output) AS
(
    SELECT input, 1, ':' ||input || ':' , 0, input, output 
    FROM graph_examle WHERE input = 1
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        c.initial_id, 
        c.level + 1, 
        c.path ||ur.input|| ':' ,
        CASE WHEN c.path LIKE '%:' ||ur.input || ':%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        ur.*
    FROM graph_examle ur
    INNER JOIN cte c ON c.output = ur.input AND c.loop = 0
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
ORDER BY initial_id, level;
```

The descending query does not work as expected. If I search by id 4, I'm expecting to see the relations:

- 4, 4->3, 4->3->2, 4->3->2->1
- 4->8, 4->8->7
- 4->11,4->11>10
- 4->15, (...)

But I'm only getting:

[image]

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte  (input, output, level, real_parent_id, path) AS
(
    SELECT 
        ur.input, ur.input, 1, output,  ( ur.input|| ' -> ' ||  ur.output)
    FROM graph_examle ur
    WHERE ur.output = 4 
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        ur_cte.input, ur.input, level + 1, ur.output, (ur_cte.path || '->' || ur.output) 
    FROM cte ur_cte
    INNER JOIN graph_examle ur on ur.input = ur_cte.real_parent_id
)
SELECT *
FROM cte  
ORDER BY path
```

Note that in my queries I'm trying to solve circular dependencies

Comment: In your example, your ascending query should also result in 1->2->3->15 and 1->2->3->15->4, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Your ascending query sounds like correct. To get what you expect, you have to concatenate the columns `path` and `output`.

Answer (score 0):

The ascending query sounds good ... maybe you can concatenate the `path` and `output` columns.

For the descending query, you can try this :

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte  (input, output, level, path, loop) AS
(
    SELECT 
        ur.input, ur.output, 1, ( ur.output|| ' -> ' ||  ur.input), 0
    FROM graph_examle ur
    WHERE ur.output = 4 
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        ur.input, ur_cte.output, level + 1, (ur_cte.path || '->' || ur.input),
        CASE WHEN ur_cte.path LIKE '%->' || ur.input THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM cte ur_cte
    INNER JOIN graph_examle ur on ur.output = ur_cte.input
    WHERE ur_cte.loop = 0
      AND ur.input IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM cte  
ORDER BY path
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LrF2Rn19)

Comment: what is the purpose of concatenating the path and output columns?

Comment: the purpose is just to get the complete path including the output which is part of it, in your query the ouput is excluded from the path.